# Trying to get jQuery Media Plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, media

I am trying to get the demo of jquery media plugin to work. Once I can get the demo working, then I will be able to start replacing the parameters with data gathered from url parameters passed.

But right now I am unable to get the demo to work locally on my pc.

http://jquery.malsup.com/media/video.html

Above is the video demo of jquery media plugin. Then when I try to make my own version of it locally I am unable to get it working.

Can you help identify any problems with the code?

http://pastebin.com/4GxaT7PX

Or since some of you asked for the actual code here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<title>Play Movie using jPlayer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
a.media   { display: block; }
div.media { font-size: small; margin: 25px; width: 100% !important }
div.media div, div.iframe_caption { font-style: italic; color: #888; }
#lr { border: 1px solid #eee; margin: auto }
div.example { padding: 20px; margin: 15px 0px; background: #ffe; clear:left; border: 1px dashed #ccc; text-align: left }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/jquery.metadata.v2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.media.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    // grab url parameters function
    $.extend({
      getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
      },
      getUrlVar: function(name){
        return $.getUrlVars()[name];
      }
    });

    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURIComponent(
            (location.search.match(RegExp("[?|&]"+name+'=(.+?)(&|$)'))||[,null])[1]
        );  
    }

    // Get object of URL parameters
    var allVars = $.getUrlVars();

    // get all the passed parameters
    var title =  $.getUrlVar('title').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var year =  $.getUrlVar('year');
    var rated =  $.getUrlVar('rated');
    var genre =  $.getUrlVar('genre').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var director =  $.getUrlVar('director').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var writer =  $.getUrlVar('writer').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var actors =  $.getUrlVar('actor').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var plot =  $.getUrlVar('plot').replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, ' ').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
    var imdbid =  $.getUrlVar('imdbid');
    var poster_src=getURLParameter('poster');
    var path=getURLParameter('path');

    // update content below
    my_title=title+' ('+year+')';
    $('#player-title').text(my_title);
    $('#director-text').html('<b>Director:</b> '+director);
    $('#writer-text').html('<b>Writer:</b> '+writer);
    $('#actors-text').html('<b>Actors:</b> '+actors);
    $('#plot-text').html(plot);
    $("#poster_show").attr("src",poster_src);

    // clean up path
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    // create player stuff
    // $('.media').html('<a href="'+path+'" class="media">Watch my movie!</a>');
    // $('#video').media( { width: 400, height: 300, autoplay: true } ); 

});
//]]>

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id='player' style="clear:both;background-color:white;padding:35px;width:40%;margin-top:45px;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;-moz-border-radius: 20px;-webkit-border-radius: 20px;-khtml-border-radius: 20px;border-radius: 20px;" class="selector">

    <h1 id='player-title'></h1>

    <a class="media {width:300, height:300}" href="http://malsup.github.com/video/clear.avi">AVI File</a>

    <span id='video'></span>

    <div id='left' style="display:block;clear:left;width:50%;border:1px;">

        <p id='director-text'></p>

        <p id='writer-text'></p>

        <p id='actors-text'></p>
        <br/><br/>
        <p id='plot-text'></p>
        <br/><br/>

    </div>

    <div id='right' style="display:block;clear:left;width:50%;">

        <img id='poster_show' src='' width='200' alt='Poster'>

    </div>

    <br style="clear:both;"/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your debugger? Where do you think the problem might be? Could you perhaps narrow this down a bit? Thanks :)

Comment: It just show's up as a link. No errors, no javascript errors, but instead of seeing a video screen, I see an html link to the video.

Comment: @croseblum - Can you post just the relevant code in your question? I suspect you're not getting a response because we're all volunteers, and looking through a big string of potentially unrelated code is not appealing :)  Just post the JavaScript you're using, the plugin, and the HTML around the area in question. Good luck!

Comment: I realize you are all volunteer's, and I had posted the code, via pastebin, isn't that the way everyone want's to show the code?

Comment: Take a look at some of the other questions in the jquery tag. You'll generally see code posted in the question body. With that said, jfiddle's are great for showing demos of what the code is doing, but it's still helpful to see it narrowed down to just the relevant parts in the question body. With that said, I wasn't trying to be snarky :) I was just trying to offer you some advice as to why your question might not be getting attention, and what you can do to fix it. Lastly, when you edit your question, you should know that it gets pushed back to the top of the list, so it's seen again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines of code that perform the conversion of the hyperlinks into actual jQuery media markup are commented out in your code.

I commented out the line for the #video element and renamed it for the elements identified by the .media class. Afterwards, I could see the video player frame with text telling me I needed to download Windows Media Player, which is the same result I get on the jQuery Media demo sites. I am on Linux, so this type of message is of course expected:

```
// create player stuff
 $('.media').html('<a href="'+path+'" class="media">Watch my movie!</a>');
 // $('#video').media( { width: 400, height: 300, autoplay: true } );

 // this tells jQuery Media which elements to bind to.
 $('.media').media( { width: 400, height: 300, autoplay: true } );
```

Assuming there are no other errors in your code, and assuming all of the query string parameters are present in the address bar, and assuming your browser has all of the necessary plugins, you should see the video.

As you may or may not be aware, all of these parameters are required in order for this to work:

```
?title=James&year=1&rated=1&genre=horror&director=me&writer=me&actor=test&plot=p&imdbid=5&poster=1&path=file:///home/james/video/s3e2.avi
```

As a side-note, consider adding a try/catch block or some checks to handle the data gracefully if something non-critical is omitted.

Comment: Thank you this solved this problem. Now to get it so it doesn't crash playing avi files. Somehow it crashes chromium and then in background launches mplayer lol.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the plugin or operating system. My suggestion would be to maybe try removing mplayer or at least the mplayer plugin in lieu of something else just as a test. Also, try on a Windows/Mac machine. Linux is terrible for Audio/Video IMHO. (I'm assuming you're on Linux ;) )

Comment: Yes I am on Linux, using Peppermint OS Two atm. Altho I am also dual-booting. But the main problem is how to get the video to play inside the browser. When I use the demo avi, it play's fine in the browser, when i play a local file it creates an mplayer execution that plays the movie in a background that i can not access or view. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you play locally, are you using an http:// link or a file:// link? Either way, it could be possible that the correct content-type isn't being returned by your local server.

Comment: I am using the file:// link. It does play the movie, just does it in the background, and not viewable in the video spot. However If i right-click and open a new movie that display's just fine inside the browser spot.

Comment: If you have Apache set up or something that could serve your video as http, it may be worth trying to use that url instead. if you think about it, this is better anyway. Your environment would be closer to what a production user would experience.

Comment: I want this to be a resource light as possible, without requiring people to install software to use this open source package.

Comment: You're just putting the file on a server is all. When you go to youtube, you don't install software, right? The videos are hosted on the web accessible via HTTP. Your problem is you're testing using a file:// scheme, which nobody does. To clarify, I'm not suggesting your users install Apache or setup a web server, but I would hope the files would be hosted somewhere. That's what jQuery is all about, after all, is enhancing Web based software, which implies one is using resources from said Web. If your goal isn't web-based, then you *might* be using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Just to clarify my end goal is to have a bash script + local web folder that is updated/created dynamically, to create a fun + light weight way of perusing and playing your local movie collection. Would you like to see some screenshots?

Comment: Here is of the first page: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/polaroidscreenshot.png/, second page: http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/3747/playerscreenshot.png

Comment: Looks pretty good! (I didn't have the css before). Not sure how to get around the file protocol issue though. You might want to post that as a separate question, just focusing on the problems with the file protocol. Just make sure you try with the HTTP first so they can rule out any other problems that could be code related. I'm sure your problem is the protocol, I'm just not 100% sure how to fix.

Comment: In other words, if you indicate it works with http on your computer but not file, then that would be a great place to start for question #2 :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient help. I truly appreciate it!